# Java CSV parser with string separator (multi-character)

Tags: java, csv, delimiter, separator

Is there any Java open source library that supports **multi-character** (i.e., String with length > 1) separators (delimiters) for CSV?

By definition, CSV = Comma-Separated Values data with a single character (',') as the delimiter. However, many other single-character alternatives exist (e.g., tab), making CSV to stand for "Character-Separated Values" data (essentially, DSV: Delimiter-Separated Values data).

Main Java open source libraries for CSV (e.g., [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)) support virtually any character as the delimiter, but not string (multi-character) delimiters. So, for data separated with strings like "|||" there is no other option than preprocessing the input in order to transform the string to a single-character delimiter. From then on, the data can be parsed as single-character separated values.

It would therefore be nice if there was a library that supported string separators natively, so that no preprocessing was necessary. This would mean that CSV now standed for "CharSequence-Separated Values" data. :-)

Comment: You could write your own lib. There is not much to it. Read every line from the file and split it with your regex or delimiters.

Comment: Not so straightforward, because CSV can have quoted fields, multiline records, etc. Also, there are countless options on quotes, escape characters, etc. Have a look at http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp for a funny overview fo the issues you may run into.

Comment: did you check [FlatPack](http://flatpack.sourceforge.net/)? I ask because per [my past research](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6657525/839601) this library seemed to have much richer API than OpenCSV

Comment: If you need to allow for the separator to be part of the data, either by quoting `007,"My name is Bond, James Bond"` or by escaping `007,My name is Bond\, James Bond` then it becomes a lot more complicated (most in the former case). The Asker does not specify if it is needed, though.

Comment: That would be a need, indeed, which is why (among many other reasons) a mature library is preferable, but all the ones I have played with seem to support on single-character separators.

Comment: @gnat FlatPack seems to support only single-character separators, as well.

Comment: I see. Did you consider _two-step approach_, then? I mean 1) replace your multi-character sequence with single char of your choice then 2) feed the result to openCSV or whatever lib

Comment: @gnat As I say in the question, "So, for data separated with strings like "|||" there is no other option that preprocessing the input in order to transform the string to a single-character delimiter." :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good question. The problem was not obvious to me until I looked at the [javadocs](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVParser.html) and realised that opencsv only supports a character as a separator, not a string....

Here's a couple of suggested work-arounds (Examples in Groovy can be converted to java).

## Ignore implicit intermediary fields

Continue to Use OpenCSV, but ignore the empty fields. Obviously this is a cheat, but it will work fine for parsing well-behaved data.

```
    CSVParser csv = new CSVParser((char)'|')

    String[] result = csv.parseLine('J||Project report||"F, G, I"||1')

    assert result[0] == "J"
    assert result[2] == "Project report"
    assert result[4] == "F, G, I"
    assert result[6] == "1"
```

or

```
    CSVParser csv = new CSVParser((char)'|')

    String[] result = csv.parseLine('J|||Project report|||"F, G, I"|||1')

    assert result[0] == "J"
    assert result[3] == "Project report"
    assert result[6] == "F, G, I"
    assert result[9] == "1"
```

## Roll your own

Use the Java String [tokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) method.

```
    def result = 'J|||Project report|||"F, G, I"|||1'.tokenize('|||')

    assert result[0] == "J"
    assert result[1] == "Project report"
    assert result[2] == "\"F, G, I\""
    assert result[3] == "1"
```

Disadvantage of this approach is that you lose the ability to ignore quote characters or escape separators..

## Update

Instead of pre-processing the data, altering it's content, why not combine both of the above approaches in a two step process:

1. Use the "roll your own" to first validate the data. Split each line and prove that it contains the requiste number of fields.
2. Use the "field ignoring" approach to parse the validated data, secure in the knowledge that the correct number of fields have been specified.

Not very efficient, but possibly easier that writing your own CSV parser :-)

Comment: Mark, the "field ignoring" approach is clever, but it won't work for strings that consist of more than 1 different characters.

What I have also thought is using the first (or last) character of the string delimiter as the separator and then remove the remaining part of the delimiter, which would appear at the start of every field. Still, this won't work if that character is a common one, i.e. it is encountered in more places than the number of delimiters.

The "rolling your own option" is not as easy as it first seems. Check secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp for some good reasons why.

Comment: I understand the limitations with both solutions. As stated the "field ignoring" approach is really only good for parsing well behaved data. As you noted if someone uses an incorrect number of separation characters it breaks assumptions you've made about the data. The "rolling your own" option is really to prove that it can be done, I'd never bother, again, unless the data is incredibly well behaved. In my experience CSV data rarely is.....

Comment: You are right. My experience, too, concurs that CSV data is often not well-formed. +1

Comment: FWIW, here's my €0.02: Create a preprocessing Reader that will transform whatever String sequence into a Character, and feed this reader to openCSV.

Comment: Apache Commons CSV doesn't seem to have this function either. According to [withRecordSeparator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withRecordSeparator-char-) documentation, Parsing currently only works for inputs with '\n', '\r' and "\r\n".

Answer (score 2):

In 2022 openCSV version 5.7.1 still doesn't support multi-character separator.

Solution - use appache commons-csv, version 1.9.0 support multi-character separator!

CSVFormat.Builder.create().setDelimiter(separator);

Comment: This should be the simplist solution, it work for me,

Comment: if the input stream is gzip stream, the commons-csv 1.10.0 will parse the column  which delimited by   multiple-characters  incorrectly, use carefully

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me, because they all assumed you could store the entire CSV file in memory allowing for easy `replaceAll` type actions.

I know it's slow, but I went with `Scanner`. It has a surprising number of features, and makes rolling your own simple CSV reader with any string you want as a record delimiter. It also lets you parse very large CSV files (I've done 10GB single files before), since you can read records one at a time.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter(">|\n");
```

I would prefer a faster solution, but no library I've found supports it. FasterXML has had an open ticket to add this funcitonality since early 2017: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

WorkAround to use delimiter || : Add dummy fields in between the needed columns

```
public class ClassName {
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private String column1;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String dummy1;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
    private String column2;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 3)
    private String dummy2;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 4)
    private String column3;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 5)
    private String dummy5;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 6)
    private String column4;
}
And then parse them using 
List<ClassName> responses = new CsvToBeanBuilder<ClassName>(new FileReader("test.csv"))
                .withType(ClassName.class)
                .withSkipLines(1) // to skip header
                .withSeparator('|')
                // to parse || , we use |
                .build()
                .parse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [**univocity-parsers**](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers), which supports multi-character delimiters and has the best performance.

As for **commons-csv**: If the input stream is a **gzip stream**, commons-csv 1.10.0 will incorrectly parse columns delimited by multiple characters, so use it carefully.

Answer (score -2):

Try [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

It does everything you need, including (and especially) handling embedded delimiters within quoted values (eg `"a,b", "c"` parses as `["a,b", "c"]`)

I've used it successfully and I liked it.

#### Edited:

Since opencsv handles only single-character separators, you could work around this thus:

```
String input;
char someCharNotInInput = '|';
String delimiter = "abc"; // or whatever
input.replaceAll(delimiter, someCharNotInInput);
new CSVReader(input, someCharNotInInput); // etc
// Put it back into each value read
value.replaceAll(someCharNotInInput, delimiter); // in case it's inside delimiters
```

Comment: OpenCSV is an excellent library, but it only supports single-character separators, not multi-character ones.

Comment: The issue is not handling any form of single-character delimiters (including embedded ones), but handling multi-character delimiters. :-)

Comment: Yes, that's the "preprocessing" step I was talking about in the question, thanks.

Comment: But such a replacement would not make a distinction between delimiters in- or outside quoted values.

Comment: It won't, but the "restoration" of the original value fixes that. In general, preprocessing is doable but not optimal, which is why I posted the question in the first place.