# Split String with special characters in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a String with many commas for example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,"one, two", 6, 7, "three, four", 8, 9
```

I want to split this string by comma(,) but parts with quotes shouldn't be splitted.
Is there a simple way to do this or should I prepare this string for example replace comma with something else:

```
1,2,3,4,5,"one#COMMA# two", 6, 7, "three#COMMA# four", 8, 9
```

and then split by comma(,)

Comment: Use a csv parser

Comment: Either use a csv parser or parse this thing yourself using a loop, `indexOf` and `substring`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java CSV parser with string separator (multi-character)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653797/java-csv-parser-with-string-separator-multi-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split by `,` followed by an optional blank characters `\s*` with a negative lookahead. This Regex would identify the commas qualified to split the input String.

```
,(?![^,]+"\s*,)\s*
```

The explanation is below and the demo is here: https://regex101.com/r/ghNMVo/1:

- `,` is a comma literally
- `(?![^,]+"\s*,)` is a negative lookahead that matches if the following characters listed between `(?!`...`)` are not found right after the comma (`,`). This basically identifies the end of a String followed by the comma (ex. `...four",`) which means, the previous comma is not matched for split as long as a String follows.

  - `[^,]+` at least one character except for the comma itself
  - `"` followed by the `"` matched literally
  - `\s*` any number of blank characters
  - `,` followed by the `,` matched literally
- `\s*` are optional blank characters

When applied to Java, don't forget to escape the characters.

```java
final String string = "1,2,3,4,5,\"one, two\", 6, 7, \"three, four\", 8, 9";
final String[] array = string.split(",(?![^,]+\"\\s*,)\\s*");
Arrays.asList(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> "one, two"
> 6
> 7
> "three, four"
> 8
> 9
> ```

Comment: What if I have more than one comma ex. "three, four, fife, six, ...." ? It doesn't work right now

Comment: This solution does not count with more than one comma as it I have worked with the sample you have provided. A different Regex is required then.